# Why does BLE require twice the bandwidth of Bluetooth Classic?

Tags: snr, bandwidth

Bluetooth Classic Basic Rate sends data at a rate of 1 Mbps using GFSK modulation in 1 MHz-wide data channels. Bluetooth Low Energy also transmits at that same data rate and modulation, however, it requires 2 MHz-wide channels. Why?

Is this about providing less stringent specifications so cheaper filters can be used in the design?
Is it about providing a better SNR?
Lastly, does the information actually use the full bandwidth or could I still see the data through a 1 MHz filter centered on the channel albeit at a reduced SNR?